# Decision Tree Overfitting - Reference Request

Tags: machine-learning, references, cart

Multiple papers and online texts start from the position that decision tree overfitting can be taken for granted.

I am not here to dispute this. However, the claim of decision tree overfitting is often uncited.

Therefore, I wondered if there was a central reference for this to justify this universal claim, or if it is broadly just taken for granted?

Any help with a citation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone may have proven this somewhere, but it is obvious for either making a single tree bigger, bigger and bigger, or also for boosted decision trees (which you could re-represent as a single tree, of course) - that's both from a theoretical perspective and to any one that has ever used them.

Theoretically, decision trees obviously can approximate any function arbitrarily well through step functions. So, they can arbitrarily closely fit the data (up to the point where identical data points have different observed outcomes). If no two data points are exactly the same, they can basically (given sufficiently deep trees - or sufficiently many somewhat less deep trees in boosted decision trees) memorize the exact value for any data point (and this really happens in practice).

In practice, you routinely watch as overfitting happens, if you look at training loss and validation loss (e.g. in a cross-validation set-up) as you keep expanding the size of a single tree (or adding more trees in a gradient boosted decision tree setup). So, I'd guess any one who uses them in practice probably would just know that this is a fact of life (unless you set various regularization parameters - although one of the most important one tends to be the complexity of trees/number of trees).

Comment: Hi @Bjorn. Thanks for your time and response. I totally get what you're saying that it is somewhat self-evident. But, it was really the central reference I was looking for